# Electron keep page loaded in background

Tags: javascript, html, electron

My goal is to give the user the opportunity to play a YouTube-Video inside the electron app. But when he change the page (currently doing it with just an  tag) that the video keeps playing. Or that the chat (with `<ul>` and `<li>`objects) have still all the messages when switching the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this something you've begun work on, and also are you having issues with the video pausing? It seems that youtube will continuously play regardless of what tab or window I'm currently in.

Comment: How did you do that? All my sites are unloading once I click a link in my menu.

Comment: I think I'd need more information to answer that question. This is a very broad request.

Comment: I have a basic html menu, created using an `<a href="#">` tag referring to another .html file - if I click it it loads the other .html file and unloads the current page. But I don't want the page to unload